# What do I add buttons to in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a minesweeper game and have fallen over at the very first hurdle; creating a grid of buttons. I have a 2D Array of buttons and I am trying to add the buttons to Form1. I would preferably do this by manually coding the buttons in. But if there is a way of creating the buttons in the designer and then adding them to a 2DArray then that would work as well I guess.

So this is essentially my problem. If I create the buttons in the designer I don't know how to assign them to a 2D array. And if I just create a 2D array of buttons manually, I don't know how to add them to the window.

Here is what I've got so far. I don't know what to replace the question marks with.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Minesweeper2
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());


            Button[,] But = new Button[10, 10];

            for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
                {
                    But[i, j] = new Button();

                    ????.Add(But[i, j]);
                }
            }

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: To add to the Form's Controls collection write: `Controls.Add(But[i, j]);` But will also need to set the Location of each Button!! You could also use a TableLayoutPanel and add to it, instead..

Comment: @TaW It says that `Controls` does not exist in the current context

Comment: Whoops, looks like you are coding the Program.cs file. Code the Form.cs instead and go to the constructor, right after the InitialzeComponent call! - Move the declaration to the class level and the for-loop intot he constructor!

Comment: @TaW Okay yeh that works great. Didn't even realise. Thank you. If you put that as the answer I'll accept it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how do it: Code the `Form1.cs`, not the `Program.cs` file!

Here write it maybe like this:

```
Button[,] But = new Button[10, 10];

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Size sz = new Size(30, 30);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
        {
            But[i, j] = new Button();
            But[i, j].Size = sz;
            But[i, j].Location = new Point(sz.Width * i, sz.Height * j);
            But[i, j].Click += Buttons_Click;
            But[i, j].Tag = new Point(i, j);

            this.Controls.Add(But[i, j]);
        }
    }

}

private void Buttons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    // ..
}
```

You can see that I have added a few lines to help later: The `Tag` contains the i & j numbers and you can get them back in the **common** click event I have created abd hooked up, too:

```
  Point ij = bt.Tag as Point;
```

Creating one or two separate functions, like Mark shows is also a great idea: You want to create the buttons only once, but later you will want to reset them for the next round..

It is also worth considering to place them on a container, like a `Panel` to help with styling and layout. For this simply replace the `this` by the container control name!

Finally: I'm not really familiar with Minefield anymore, so I don't know just how many data each mine should be able to store. **If** you want to store the data right with the `Buttons` it may be better to create a `Mine class`; it would include the coordinates, the field state and maybe the neighbour data and maybe also methods the Mine is respnsible for.. As I wrote it, the one (i.e. precious) `Tag` field is 'wasted' with a simple two-integer struture..

Answer (score 2):

In you code, you should add buttons inside the `Form1` class, not in `Program`.

As i can see from this code, it's a WindowsForms Application, so move your code to **Form1** class.

You can make some function *PostInitialization()* in Form1 class.

```
private void PostInitialization() {
    Button[,] buttons = new Button[10, 10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            Button button = new Button();
            // change *button* properties here if needed

            buttons[i, j] = button;
            this.Controls.Add(buttons[i, j]);
        }
    }
}
```

And call it exactly after `InitializaComponent` function in **Form1** constructor.